# iOS Bottom Layout Guide in the wrong position

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Stackoverflow hive-mind!

I have come to you with a serious headache, a unsolvable obstacle!

The issue's as follows :

I have a UIPageViewController that has four pages and two types of content UIViewControllers - ContentViewController and UserAccessViewController. The first three pages are just three ContentViewControllers with different content inside (different image and text). The last page's the UserAccessViewController that hosts a GUI for a User to SignIn or SignUp. The "main" UIView for the UserAccessViewController's of class UIScrollView, maybe this is worth noting.

All of the controls on the ViewControllers are constrained to the Bottom Layout Guide as a starting point. You can imagine it like a flow. The bottom-most control's constrained to the Bottom Layout Guide and the next control's constrained to the bottom-most and so on, and so forth. (See SIDE-NOTICE below for an explanation why everything's constrained with the Bottom and not the Top Layout Guide in mind).

So, we've come to the issue at hand. Firstly, this only happens to the fourth page, UserAccessViewController.

On iOS 8.1 everything works fine and as intended, but on iOS 7.1, the Bottom Layout Guide doesn't get positioned correctly, which, in consequence, removes all of my content off screen (remember, everything's constrained above the Bottom Layout guide).

iOS 8.1 frame :

`UIView of class _UILayoutGuide's frame : [0.00, 0.00] - [0.00, 20.00]` -> TOP
`UIView of class _UILayoutGuide's frame : [0.00, 538.00] - [0.00, 0.00]` -> BOTTOM (DITTO!)

iOS 7.1 frame :

`UIView of class _UILayoutGuide's frame : [0.00, 0.00] - [0.00, 20.00]` -> TOP
`UIView of class _UILayoutGuide's frame : [0.00, 0.00] - [0.00, 0.00]` -> BOTTOM (WTF ?!)

Things I've tried to rectify the problem :

1. Remove the constraints completely, to see if the maybe the constraints alter the Bottom Layout Guide somehow. 
   --> Results : Negative. Removing the constraints didn't change anything. Bottom Layout Guide still not positioned correctly.
2. That's it! I've no idea what can I change :(.

Hope the collective hive-mind will deem me worthy of assistance!

---

SIDE-NOTICE : If you're wondering why the hell did I focus on the Bottom Layout Guide and not the Top one, the reason lies in the fact that, when the controls were constrained to the Top Layout Guide as reference, when the constrains were modified in viewDidLoad of a page that isn't the first, it would result in a twitch - the controls would teleport into position. I couldn't solve it differently than to use the Bottom Layout Guide instead of the Top one.

Comment: You probably thought of this, but just in case: are you constraining to margins? I don't think they're supported in iOS 7. I get a warning when I inadvertently do this (it's easy to do -- it's the default in iOS 8).

Comment: @AnnaDickinson - I'm not constraining to margins, "Relative to margin"'s checked OFF for all of the constraints. I did notice one thing, when I swap the class of the "main" UIView from UIScrollView to UIVIew it works, but my "move-the-keyboard-when-it-covers-a-textfield" mechanism is borked.

Comment: Is your UIScrollView constrained to its superview?  It needs to be: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: The UIScrollView is not constrained to it's Superview because the UIScrollView's the "container" view for the UserAccessViewController and constraints cannot be set on these views. It shouldn't need any constraints, in this particular case.

Comment: That would make sense, but the UIScrollView *must* be constrained to its superview as per that link -- it doesn't function correctly otherwise.  If it's not possible to do that, you'll need to rework the design, unfortunately... not sure if this idea is applicable, but I often put a transparent, background "sizing view" behind everything within a given container.  The Sizing View is constrained to the container, and everything else is constrained to it.  Makes it easier to deal with some types of constraints.

Comment: You are right, it has to be, so I guess I'll have to inject a "helper" view just for layout-ing purposes. 

Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: Hope it works out! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That would make sense, but the UIScrollView must be constrained to its
>   superview as per that link -- it doesn't function correctly otherwise.
>   If it's not possible to do that, you'll need to rework the design,
>   unfortunately... not sure if this idea is applicable, but I often put
>   a transparent, background "sizing view" behind everything within a
>   given container.  The Sizing View is constrained to the container, and
>   everything else is constrained to it.  Makes it easier to deal with
>   some types of constraints

The answer was provided by Anna Dickinson, so I'll mark this as resolved with the answer quoted.